# Localized partials in Middleman

Tags: ruby, localization, internationalization, middleman

In Middleman, is it possible to localize partials? I haven't been able to find any documentation for this. But I'm working on long pieces with complex markup, and it may be necessary to adjust the templates themselves for localization. I'd like to be able to narrow these sections down to partials so that I don't have to fall back on maintaining entirely separate templates when this happens. Is there a place I can put partials such that the `partial` command will look up a partial as *partial_name*.*language*.html.erb?

It might also be possible to dynamically construct partials argument if it's possible to tell what language I'm in within the ERb. So I could do something like `<%= partial "my_piece/partials/#{current_lang}/tricky_section" %>`, but I don't know if something like `current_lang` exists.

Comment: Why don't you check for the language inside the partial? and based on it generate the wanted marckup

Comment: @KarimTarek The documentation didn't explain how to do this

Comment: just plain old Ruby :)

Comment: @KarimTarek What do you mean? How could I check the language without knowing how what variable held it? I mean, I know now, as you can see below, but not because the documentation said anything about a `lang` variable.

Comment: I mean inside your partial you can test `lang' as you already knew about it, so instead of having two partials, you can have one partial and inside of it do an `if statement` like `if lang == 'en' #do something` `else #do something else`

Comment: @KarimTarek I only learned about `lang` after writing my question, which I was able to do browsing the Github issues for the project

Answer (score 0):

On the issue tracker, I found [documentation](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/924) of how I can use the second option I can do `<%= partial "partials/my_piece/#{lang}/tricky_section" %>`, or directly embed logic that otherwise keys off of `lang`.

Comment: Leaving open for now, because being able to rely on  localization's magic template lookup for partials would be preferred.